# Why does my screen in react native show that the parameters I passed through my navigation are undefined?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-navigation

So in summary I'm trying to pass my 'name' variable from my 'Signup.js' screen to my 'Home.js' by passing parameters to routes through my `navigation.navigate()` function.

So Here's my Signup.js Screen:

```js
import firebaseConfig from '../firebase';
import {
  Pressable,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {
  getAuth,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

import styles from './Stylesheets/Signup-Stylesheet';

const Signup = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  const [name, setName] = useState(''); //THIS VARIABLE NEEDS TO GO TO HOME.JS
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  function handleSignUpData() {
    console.log(name);
    setLoading(prevLoading => !prevLoading);
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then(userCredential => {
        const user = userCredential.user;
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error.message));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
      if (user) {
        navigation.navigate('Home', {name: name});
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.welcome}>
        <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>
          Hello! Tell me more about yourself:
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.form}>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={text => setName(text)}
          placeholderTextColor={'#3c2a21'}
          placeholder="Name"
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
          placeholderTextColor={'#3c2a21'}
          placeholder="Email"
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
          secureTextEntry
          placeholderTextColor={'#3c2a21'}
          placeholder="Password"
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <Pressable onPress={handleSignUpData} style={styles.submit}>
          {loading ? (
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" />
          ) : (
            <Text style={styles.submitText}>Submit</Text>
          )}
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

And here's my Home.js screen:

```js
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, BackHandler, Alert} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

const Home = ({route}) => {
  console.log(route.params.name);
```

At this point in time as long as it logs it to the console it's fine. But I keep getting this error:

```js
cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I've gone through the react navigation docs and I'm still not sure what's wrong with my code. Maybe It's the `useEffect()` function? So I'd really like some help here!

I've tried to change the parameters to something like:

`navigation.navigate('Home', {username: name})` but I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you putting Home in StackNavigator?